# How to enumerate the various Account Rights Constants of a local computer?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I am trying to enumerate all the 'Account Rights Constants' (eg:SeBatchLogonRight, SeInteractiveLogonRight, etc) programmatically. I have posted the MSDN link for the same.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/account-rights-constants

I could find API's for enumerating ' Privilege constants ' i.e  `LsaEnumeratePrivileges()` defined in ntlsa.h , but could not find for account rights. Are there any API to query these constants, or should i do  hard-code of these constants.

PS: I am trying to query the SID , Domain and Account Names of these constants by passing it to `LsaEnumerateAccountsWithUserRight()`

Comment: Have you tried LookupPrivilegeValue with the constants defined here? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/account-rights-constants

Comment: LookupPrivilegeValue() function is used to obtain the LUID for a particular privilege. Actually i am trying to query all the constants itself for a system (without any account name / domain name)

Comment: @kvr do u suggest to hard-code the constants instead?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no API to enumerate Account Rights specially. Maybe you can use another way: to enumerate the local user Sid, then use [`LsaEnumerateAccountRights`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ntsecapi/nf-ntsecapi-lsaenumerateaccountrights) to enumerate the privileges of each SID, and filter out the privileges with "LogonRight"